# SharePoint Management Shell Add-PnPFieldFromXml

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have problem with SharePoint Management Shell sommand

For example:
$FieldXML= ""
Add-PnPFieldFromXml -FieldXml $FieldXML

Error message :
Add-PnPFieldFromXml : Input string was not in a correct format.
At line:3 char:1

- Add-PnPFieldFromXml -FieldXml $Field
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPFieldFromXml], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Fields.AddFieldFromXml
  ```

Thank You for any advice

Comment: Full example:$FieldXML= "<Field Type='User' Name='ProjectManager' Group='Test' ID='$([GUID]::NewGuid())' DisplayName='Project Manager' UserSelectionMode='PeopleAndGroups'></Field>"
Add-PnPFieldFromXml -FieldXml $FieldXML

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add StaticName as an additional parameter to fix it. Here is an example for you to refer

```
$xml = ('<Field Type=' + "`"$type`"" + ' StaticName=' + "`"$iName`"" +' Name=' + "`"$iName`"" + ' DisplayName=' + "`"$dName`"" + ' Group=' + "`"$group`"" + ' Description=' + "`"$description`"" + ' ID=' + "`"$id`"" + '/>')
```

Comment: I added static name:

Comment: $Field='<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="SingleTextDemo1" Required="TRUE" Group="TEST"  ID="'+$MyGuid+'" MaxLength="255" StaticName="SingleTextDemo1" Name="SingleTextDemo1" Description="Provide Name for the Demo" />'

Comment: I tryied it with twoo SiteCollections A and B. Error appeared during connection to Site Collection A after few succesfull commands. .
New info is that when I am connected to Site Collection B, it is working well. It means that something happened In Site Collection A but I dont know what ...